# Resizing a View to ID card size

Tags: android, android-view

I have a Custom Camera in my App, below the screenshoot :

[image]

As you see, there is a green line on my Surfaceview. I need to resize that view as a Visa/Passport size (it is about 125mm x 88mm or 1011 x 638 pixels). Here how I inflated the green line :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.border_view, frameLayout, false);
//view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
this.frameLayout.addView(view);
```

I have try some answer related with resize view but I don't get the best result. And I know the screen width/height and the density every Android device is different, so I don't get the right value for height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you comment out this line :

```
//view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

You can set the width and height like this:

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(1011, 638));
```

Comment: yes I try it before but if I rotate the camera, the width and height is not suitable with the potrait screen